# add user friendly json editor to django admin

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-admin, django-jsonfield

I have a django app, using also `rest_framework`, and a model `Product` with field of type `JSONField`. so data is stored as `JSON` in `Postgres`, Now I want to provide the admin with a nice user friendly way on how he can change the json field `(names/keys and values)`. is there an extension for that or is there a faster way on how to do that.

here is the column definition in the database.
`my_column = JSONField(default={"editorial1": "text 1", "editorial_2": "text2", "editorial_3": "text"})`

BOTH KEYS AND VALUES SHOULD BE EDITABLE BY THE ADMIN

The admin should not know anything about JSON, and should not enter/edit any json format field

Answer (score 5):

You can use `prettyjson`'s `PrettyJSONWidget`:

```
class ProductModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            ...
            'my_column',
        )
        widgets = {
            'my_column': PrettyJSONWidget(),
        }
```

Comment: `pip install django-prettyjson` (I use 0.3.0, but there can be a newer one out there)

Comment: thnks for the info. this would require that the use have to have some knowledge about json. our users do not know anything about that. therefore the https://github.com/kevinmickey/django-prettyjson seemed to be better i would say

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using the `django-admin-json-editor`. Not the best thing in the world, but it does the trick

https://github.com/abogushov/django-admin-json-editor

Answer (score 2):

You can try https://github.com/jrief/django-entangled

In comparison to the editors mentioned above, it doesn't replace the widget used to render the JSON, but allows to override the `ModelForm` which otherwise is generated by Django's `ModelAdmin`.